# Issue in wait() method

Tags: java

```
package sample;

public class Wait2 {
  boolean flag = true;
  private long waitTime = 10;
  Object obj = new Object();
  public static void main(String args[]){
    final Wait2 wait = new Wait2();


  //Create two threads:
  Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
     public void run() {
       wait.A();
     }
  };

  Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
     public void run() {
       wait.B();
     }
  };

  //Start the downloads.
  thread1.start();
  thread2.start();

  }
  public synchronized void A(){
    waitAndSweep("A");
  }

  public synchronized void B(){
    waitAndSweep("B");
  }
  protected void waitAndSweep(final String caller)  {

    synchronized (obj) {
      while (!flag) { try {
        obj.wait();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      } }
    }
    flag = false;
      long waitTime = getWaitTime();  

      if (waitTime > 0)
        try {
          wait(waitTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      System.out.println(caller + waitTime ); 
      SomeWork();


  }
  private void SomeWork() {
    this.waitTime = this.waitTime  + 1;
    flag=true;
    synchronized (obj) {
      obj.notify();
    }


  }
  public long getWaitTime() {
    return waitTime;
  }
  public void setWaitTime(long waitTime) {
    this.waitTime = waitTime;
  }

}
```

In this I am trying to achieve to wait() and notify() but there is some error in line ---> wait(waitTime) while debugging it is stuck there. If I use Thread.sleep(waitTime) instead of wait(waitTime). It is working fine. Any ideas pls?

Comment: "there is some error" is *never* enough detail...

Answer (score 1):

What's the purpose of your test?

You are making confusion about Sleep and Wait methods.
Wait can be woken up by calling Notify method from another process whereas Sleep cannot.

Wait and Notify must occur in a synchronized block on the monitor object whereas Sleep does not.

You get stucked in debug probably because the Notify method is never called whereas replacing Wait by Sleep all works fine due to you are never locking your thread but just freeze it for a little bit.